# Ionic DeepLinker for lazy loaded page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to implement [ionic deeplinker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/2.0.0/api/navigation/DeepLinker/) in my app. I am trying to make it work with pages that are in it's own module i.e, lazy loaded page.

Here is what I have in app.module.ts

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{},{
  links:[
    { component: HomePage, name: 'Home', segment: 'home' },
    { component: DemoPage, name: 'Demo', segment: 'demo/:postId' ,defaultHistory: [HomePage]  },
    { component: 'OtherPage', name: 'Other', segment: 'Other' ,defaultHistory: [HomePage]  },
]
```

Note that **otherPage** is in quotes. I want to lazy load it.

The **other.module.ts** is as follows.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { OtherPage } from './other';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OtherPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(OtherPage),
  ],
})
export class OtherPageModule {}
```

How to I achive lazy loading and deeplinking.

Note here that I am using the tabs template.Here is an issue on github on tabs not [working with deeplinking](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/9183)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set in [IonicPage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/). Deeplinking in Ionicpages is achieved by setting the segment and URL information in the page.

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'Other',
  segment: 'Other',
  defaultHistory: ['HomePage']
})
```

Comment: Tried using V3 as you mentioned. It does not work with tabs template. Just loads the home page.

Comment: Also, deeplinker is also available in ionic 3 as well see here https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/IonicModule/#forRoot

Comment: @krv fair enough.. got confused when you linked to version 2 docs in the question.. Tabs is an issue in Ionic itself.. the devs will have to check it

Comment: Can you tell me what does the `name` property represent?

Comment: name is the custom name you can use when you push using navController. _the name property will be set to the class name if it isn't provided. Changing the name of the link is extremely simple. To change the name used to link to the component, simply pass it in the decorator_

Comment: @krv @Suraj Does it works for you? We need to call it  like `this.navCtrl.push('Other');` right?